Delete widget immediately
I know this problem has been already discussed, and I know it has to do with the fact that deleteLater() only is effective after passing again control to the event loop.
Here there is my simple code:
squares = MainWindow.findChildren(QtWidgets.QFrame,"squaresFrame")
print(f"{len(squares)} before delete") #they are 10

for square in squares:
    square.deleteLater()
        
squares = MainWindow.findChildren(QtWidgets.QFrame,"squaresFrame")
print(f"{len(squares)} after delete") #they are still 10

The two prints always print the same number, in my case 10, meaning that the squares are still around.
Is there a way to delete the squares immediately?
For example how can I pass control to the event loop and take it back to my script without user interaction?

QApplication.processEvents(), but that's not guaranteed to be fully effective immediately, as deletion may still be "delayed" due to various aspects. Why do you actually need to verify that, and why has it to be "immediately" reliable?

Use sip.delete.
